# Need clarification of the target and lib compiler options

Tags: typescript

I find I'm confused by the target and lib options and how they interact with the features supported in the source code. I feel the docs need improving a little so am asking here before raising an issue.

I naively assumed that target specifies the version of JS that the output code requires to run (with the addition of a module loader). Thus we can always use all the advanced JS features (like object spread) that TS supports in our source and the compiler generates suitable code for the target we specify. I assume it had polyfills etc at hand and the code would just run on the target VM.

However the docs for the lib option specify the default libs depend on the target. But, libs effect what source types are available and so effect what code we can use. Thus the source features we can use depend on the target. That is not as I expected. I should say my understanding of lib is that they are typings with a different API, though the docs do not really say what they are.

I can see that here are some language features that do not depend on types and others that do. However it's not clear if that's part of the reason for this situation.

Can someone please clarify this?

A secondary question is why is there both an ES6 and an ES2015 lib when they are usual documented as being the same thing.

thanks

Answer (score 208):

(This started as a comment but it got too long.)

It's a bit confusing partly because there's some history behind it. I'm not qualified to answer this authoritatively but I've been following TypeScript since early development and this is my understanding:

- `--target` tells the compiler what library version to include while compiling (for example `ES5` will give a compiler error if you use `Promise`, but `ES6` will know all about `Promise`) *and* what version of JS is *emitted* by the compiler (for example `ES5` will down-compile class syntax, but `ES6` will leave it in).
- `--lib` was added later to give you better control over what library version to use while compiling *without changing the emitted JS target*. For example, a common problem was that you may include polyfills for ES6 library features, such as `Promise`, but you want to target ES5 browsers by down-compiling `class` syntax. Before `--lib` was around you either had to target `ES6` to avoid compile errors about `Promise`, then down-compile *again* using Babel, or you could target `ES5` and provide your own type definition for `Promise` so that the compiler doesn't give you an error. Now with `--lib` you can simply say your `--target ES5` and `--lib ES6`, and the compiler will not complain about `Promise` but still down-compile to ES5.
- Neither option will cause TS to emit any library polyfills (`Promise`, etc), as you evidently found out; it's your responsibility to provide the correct runtime libraries. It only emits a few down-level language compatibility helpers, like `__extends` and `__awaiter` (the difference being that `class` or `async` is not just an API that can be polyfilled at runtime, it's a language feature with syntax implications). The `--lib` option is just your way of getting the right level of compile checking based on what you know you are going to have at runtime.
- As for why there's both `ES6` and `ES2015`, that's just because ECMAScript changed the name and TS left the old name as a valid option for backwards compatibility. :)

You'll find a lot of this covered in these TS issues:

- [#4168 - Normalize our lib files by compiler settings](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4168)
- [#6974 - Proposal: Modularize Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6974)

TSConfig Reference links:

- [target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target)
- [lib](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib)

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer. So I see the roots of the confusion are that ```-target``` does those 2 things, plus some language features are down-compiled while others are not but do require a lib for use in the source..

Comment: That also answers another question - why on earth you would use TS AND Babel :) So a good way to target many current browsers is target ES6 in TS with Babel transpiling down to ES5.

Comment: @Aaron In my version of TypeScript lib.es6.d.ts and lib.es2015.d.ts are slightly different. ES6 is defined as es2015 (language) with dom, dom.iterable, webworker.importscript and scripthost.

Comment: @cquezel You are looking at the [generated](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.0/src/lib/README.md) `es6.d.ts` file and the `es2015.d.ts` file, but `es6.d.ts` is what gets used if you use `--target es6`, which is equivalent to `--lib es6,dom,dom.iterable,scripthost` (as stated in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)). If you use `--lib es6` by itself you will not get DOM, etc. `--lib es6` and `--lib es2015` give you the same thing. `--target es6` and `--target es2015` also gives you the same thing.

Comment: "It's a bit confusing partly because there's some history behind it" Modern JS in general.