# Cannot import typings for Proxy

Tags: node.js, typescript, proxy, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

I am trying to import the type information for Proxy, see picture:

[image]

It looks like it's located at `lib.es6.d.ts`, but when I try to select that, I get:

[image]

Anybody see a similar issue with Proxy and Webstorm? I have seen it many times, finally asking about it.

Comment: Have you told Typescript to target ES6? Older environments don't support Proxy.

Comment: hey @loganfsmyth I am not sure what you mean...I would think that TS would support ES6..I guess what you mean is that TS cannot compile it down to ES5?

Comment: Right, "targetting ES6" means you've told Typescript to output ES6 code, which would allow you to use `Proxy`. If you're outputting ES5, proxies will not work consistently on older environments and so are not allowed.

Comment: Yeah I see, yeah Proxy is very useful for libraries..I got it to compile as I indicated in my answer but not sure how kosher it really is, let me know what you think.

Comment: For reference, where Proxy is available in the browser: http://caniuse.com/#search=proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript varies in what it actually allows, based on what output language version you specify. If you tell Typescript that you want to output code compatible with ES5 for instance, it will not load the `lib.es6.d.ts` definitions, because you haven't told it you'll be running in an environment that supports that stuff. For instance see [Typescript- What is target in tsconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415942/typescript-what-is-target-in-tsconfig) and [Need clarification of the target and lib compiler options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093758/need-clarification-of-the-target-and-lib-compiler-options).

In your case, since `Proxy` only exists on modern environments, I'm assuming that you never expect your code to work on older environments. Based on that assumption, you should be safe in telling Typescript

```
target: 'es6'
```

in your Typescript configuration.

Comment: this makes sense, I will see if that works, although I need to target ES5 though because library code needs to run on ES5. There are some proxy polyfill libraries not sure if you know how good they are?

Comment: If it needs to work on ES5, you absolutely cannot use `Proxy`. The whole reason proxy exists is to support functionality that was impossible to achieve in ES5, so it's impossible to polyfill. If all you're using is `get` then you could explore using `Object.defineProperty` to add getters and setters for the properties you need, but there's no way in ES5 to have a catch-all property access.

Comment: Yeah...I know what you mean...what about this https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill

Comment: https://github.com/sumanjs/suman/blob/master/lib/test-suite-helpers/make-test-suite.ts#L115

Comment: There are boat-loads of things wrong with that, but at the end of the day all it does for `get` is call `Object.defineProperty`. If that's all you need for what you're doing, your code will be infinitely more readable if you just call `Object.defineProperty` yourself instead of pretending to use a proxy when you're not actually doing that.

Comment: yeah..Proxy was available starting in Node.js version 6. Honest question for you, what is the most recent browser that does not support Proxy? I might just support Node versions >= 6, and browsers that support Proxy.

Comment: It's mostly if you want to support IE, or older mobile browsers. Take a look at https://caniuse.com/#search=Proxy. It's really up to you as far as what you feel needs to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I can get it to compile like so (in my case using Function as the return type):

```
   const getProxy = function (method: Function, rule: Object, props?: Array<string>): Function {

        return new Proxy(method, {
          get: function (target, prop) {
               return function(){ }  // everytime, a function is returned.
          }
       });

   }
```

so that seems to work for me for the moment.

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it's the right approach :) See my answer.

Comment: haha yeah but it kinda makes sense tho...it's returning a function by way of a proxy? idk