# Why do I need a polyfill with Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Lets say I want to use `Object.values()`. In order to use this, I have to set `"lib":["es2017"]`. But then I have `"target":"es6"`.

The way I read this as a new Typescript user is that I am writing with `es2017` methods and it's outputting `es6` code.

So my question is this, why do I need a polyfill, and how do I select a reliable one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Object.values with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966362/how-to-use-object-values-with-typescript)

Comment: Also see [Need clarification of the target and lib compiler options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093758/need-clarification-of-the-target-and-lib-compiler-options/42097465#42097465)

Comment: Not a duplicate of `Object.values with typescript`, I'm just using it as a concrete example. Will look at the other suggestions for duplicates. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Typescript has as little runtime impact as possible. Except for a very limited number of utilitiy functions it has no other runtime behavior. This is by design.

Typescript can't know the exact environment you code will run on and what level of support it has for what feature. When specify a lib or target option you tell Typescript there will be runtime support for the required features, not Typescript problem how this happens.

Comment: I understand that. But why doesn't `lib es2017` and `target es6` allow me to write `es2017` code and have it run on an `es6` target? From what I understand, I still need a polyfill.

Comment: @LukePighetti maybe this answer can shed more light on your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043439/using-latest-javascript-features-in-typescript-such-as-es2018/51044240#51044240

Comment: @LukePighetti or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986494/what-does-the-typescript-lib-option-really-do/50987516#50987516

Answer (score 11):

**TypeScript** distinguishes between **API calls** and **syntax**.

The TypeScript compiler [levels down the syntax](https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1596986750509154304) (recognizable by special characters like `=>`, `?`, `` ` ``, `#` and keywords like `class` or `static`) but not the API. To polyfill API calls, such as [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) (introduced in `ES2019`), you would need an extra compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

### Example

The following compiler config will convert the nullish coalescing operator (`??`) and the `class` itself but not the API call to `Array.prototype.flat` (although it is not present in `ES5`):

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2019"],
    "target": "ES5"
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
export class MyConverter {
  static flatten(numbers?: (number | number[])[]) {
    return (numbers ?? []).flat();
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.MyConverter = void 0;
var MyConverter = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyConverter() {
    }
    MyConverter.flatten = function (numbers) {
        return (numbers !== null && numbers !== void 0 ? numbers : []).flat();
    };
    return MyConverter;
}());
exports.MyConverter = MyConverter;
```