# Cannot setup TypeScript to use `using` keyword

Tags: typescript

I am using TypeScript 5.2 version, I have following setup:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "esnext.disposable", // Value is not accepted.
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

and the following file:

```
const getFile = () => {
    return {
        [Symbol.dispose]: () => {
            console.log('x!')
        }
    }
}

console.clear()

using(const file = getFile()) { // ERROR: Cannot find name 'using'.ts(2304)
    // do something with file
}
```

```
  "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
```

But I cannot use the `using` keyword, get error: // Cannot find name 'using'.ts(2304)

It seems that `"esnext.disposable"` is not accepted.

How to setup TypeScript to use disposable? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, and you'll also need to polyfill `Symbol.dispose` to get it to work in current JS environments. The following will work:

```
// <polyfill>

// the interfaces are only necessary if you're not including https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/esnext.disposable.d.ts as a `lib` option
interface SymbolConstructor {
    readonly dispose: unique symbol
}

interface Disposable {
    [Symbol.dispose](): void
}

// @ts-ignore - if it already exists as a readonly property, this is a no-op anyway
Symbol.dispose ??= Symbol('Symbol.dispose')

// </polyfill>

const getFile = () => {
    return {
        [Symbol.dispose]: () => {
            console.log('x!')
        }
    }
}

console.log(1)

// note the enclosing block, which acts as the scope for the resource
{
    using file = getFile()
    console.log(2)
}

console.log(3)
// console output: 1, 2, "x!", 3
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-us7Q7PV6vUa3LACuENAq0gBCNWvUNnZ1nM6G-pwKPQGMARnVODAqMoTJIRCU4SYmlAYWg9AA1oyecz6ARWCMSixCPsbH5QIgxqWXW43YxMFNnRIq2QtHqbabzVbI8Ck6Bw1nLNGAQAmdXp9eRzc5gEAZnVuAPHAkemv61zjO3jIARPGn4yT5ggA)

[TS blog post explaining the new syntax](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-2-beta/#using-declarations-and-explicit-resource-management)

Comment: I thought TypeScript will generate the polyfill by using "esnext", is my assumption wrong?

Comment: @Radex see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633273/why-do-i-need-a-polyfill-with-typescript

Comment: this does not work anymore. The `dispose` is readonly and we cannot assign it. I cannot get this to work :(

Comment: @JobaDiniz I changed the code, I think this version should be a bit more robust to different libs/targets