Why doesn't TypeScript downlevel array.with?
The tsconfig manual states that the target property should set which features are downlevelled.

The target setting changes which JS features are downleveled and which are left intact. For example, an arrow function () => this will be turned into an equivalent function expression if target is ES5 or lower.

In my tsconfig.json I have set my target to be es6:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./src/@types", "./src/global.d.ts", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "jest.config.js"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules"]
}

As such I would expect the feature Array.prototype.with to be downlevelled to something that works in ES6. However, it isn't and this is causing issues running in Chrome 109 (last working version for Windows 7/8 users).
Is there a reason that this isn't the case?

Because you also set lib to ESNext, thereby including ES2023 definitions. It doesn't downlevel APIs, only syntax.

@jonrsharpe No, this doesn't affect what it compiles to, only which features tsc will have types for and not error on. By which I mean, if I remove esnext from the lib it just errors. It doesn't change the compiled code

That's the expected behaviour, yes. I'd suggest reading e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74594356/3001761
