# How do I use Promises with TypeScript when targeting es5?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, promise, es5-compatiblity

```
Promise.all<any, any>(ajaxRequests).then(()=> {
    console.log("done");
});
```

The above code gives the following compiler error:

```
TS2585: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.
```

I'm not familiar with what this compiler `lib` option is and what implications it has if I were to change it.

---

I'm trying to target older browsers and need to support `es5` I believe. I assume this can be done by transpiling/polyfilling? My typescript config is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "declaration": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "module" : "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "src/*"
    ],

    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: you should probably add something like @types/es6-promise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to your compiler options:

```
"lib": [
        "dom",
        "es5",
        "es2015.promise"
    ]
```

The `lib` options are described in more detail [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42097465/3479456) an explanation of the difference between `target` and `lib`.

That being said, if using `es6` is acceptable to you, then I think you can just set `target` to `"es6"` instead of messing with `lib`.