# cannot find name 'fetch' and 'Header' in typescript

Tags: typescript, fetch

I am using fetch in my angular project and the code snippet is as follows:

```
        fetch(
            'www.example.com', {
            headers: new Headers({
            'Origin': location.origin
            }),
            mode: 'cors'
        })
```

However, the website runs without problem but it gives error as below:
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'fetch'.
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Headers'.

I searched the ways to solve this problem and tried add 
"lib": [ "es5", "dom"] in "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json as below, but got the same error. I also tried adding "es6" inside, but no luck.
I am running out of idea and could you please help.

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [ "es5", "dom"],
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "allowUnreachableCode": true
    },
```

Comment: Try `es2018` instead of `es5`. I'm not sure why `es6` didn't work, but `fetch` definitely isn't in `es5`.

Comment: Should I change the target as well or just in the lib?

Comment: Probably. Honestly after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093758/need-clarification-of-the-target-and-lib-compiler-options) answer about the difference I'm still not sure what the right answer is.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one lib (dom.iterable) in your tsconfig.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable"]
},
```